# Iphone Application - Header - do a post request on every view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an application with many views. On each page, there is a "header" that states info like Name / Score / etc.

Now, on each and every view, I am doing a POST request to get this data. Is it possible to not do this everytime, and instead just do an update only when needed?

Please give me ideas.

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dan Ray pointed out, `NSUserDefaults` would be the easiest way to accomplish this. If you had a lot of data and wanted to keep it all together then you could write it to an XML file.

Here is an example of using `NSUserDefaults`:

```
// Setting.
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"MyKey"];

// Retrieving that object.
NSString* aString = (NSString*)[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"MyKey"];
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for NSUserDefaults. Depending on how often that source data changes, you might only need to do that web request once *ever*!

Answer (score 1):

You could establish an actual TCP connection to your server and transmit the data when it changes.